# Format date in javascript with time

Tags: javascript

How would I format a date in javascript in the format: `June 2, 2013, 1:05 p.m.`

Here is a relevant link, but I'm still having trouble getting this exact formatting, based on `Date()`. http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3

Comment: Elaborate on "trouble". Paste exact code you use, results you get and results you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write a *function* to get bits of the date for you and `return` an *Object* which lets you build a string as easily as string concatenation of *Object* properties.

The example below will always base answer on UTC time

```
var easyDate = (function () {
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        thstndrd = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th'];
    return function (d) {
        var dow = d.getUTCDay(),
            dom = d.getUTCDate(),
            moy = d.getUTCMonth(),
            y = d.getUTCFullYear(),
            h = d.getUTCHours(),
            m = d.getUTCMinutes(),
            s = d.getUTCSeconds();
        return {
            dom: '' + dom,
            th: thstndrd[dom % 10],
            day: days[dow],
            moy: '' + (moy + 1),
            month: months[moy],
            year: '' + y,
            ampm: h < 12 ? 'a.m.' : 'p.m.',
            hh: h < 10 ? '0' + h : '' + h,
            sh: '' + (h % 12 || 12),
            mm: m < 10 ? '0' + m : '' + m,
            ss: s < 10 ? '0' + s : '' + s,
        };
    };
}());

var o = easyDate(new Date());
// Object {dom: "2", th: "nd", day: "Sunday", moy: "6", month: "June"…}
o.month + ' ' + o.dom + ', ' + o.sh + ':' + o.mm + ' ' + o.ampm;
// "June 2, 8:43 p.m."
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be useful to you: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest moment.js. here it is: http://momentjs.com/

import it and do this

```
moment().format('LLL');
```

this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

At w3schools you can find a complete [reference to Javascript's Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Then you can use the methods to combine into a string of your liking.

```
var d = new Date();

d.getHours() + ":" + ...
```

There isn't a method to get the month name, you will need to get the number and create a switch.

The hour is in 24h format, so you have to convert and calculate if it is `am` or `pm`.

The day and year you can get directly using `getDate()` and `getFullYear()`

**References**

- [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: If you're linking to documentation, link to the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date